# Проблема установки Java на Windows

Tags: java, windows, install

Посетил веб-сайт Java в качестве загрузки использовал интерактивную установку через exe-шник в 1.8 мб. После успешной установки языка ввел команду в cmd `javac имяфайла.java` - "javac" - не является внутренней или внешней командой..... Ввел просто `java -version` никакой ошибки нет, также проверил добавлен ли патч `echo %Path%` - в листе патча есть `....Java/javapath..`. Как мне быть? Я уже переустанавливал джаву несколько раз. Интересно только у меня такая проблема?

Comment: Как обстоит вопрос с переменными среды?

Comment: @icYFTL, тоже самое, в терминале она добавлена в Path но почему то ее нет в переменных средах. Добавил переменную Java с адресом, но она почему-то исчезает после закрытия сред

Comment: Попробуйте запустить оснастку из под администратора. Откройте cmd от имени администратора и выполните команду sysdm.cpl